# Bind an image-src from array of objects

Tags: vue.js

How can I bind the `prod.src`?

```
<v-row>
    <v-col v-for="prod in products" :key="prod.id" cols="12" md="6" lg="3">

          <v-btn outline block class="primary">{{prod.id}}</v-btn>                   
          <img :src="require(`${prod.src}`)" />     <!-- I was trying this -->

    </v-col>        
</v-row>

<script>
   export default {
      data: () => ({
        products: [         
           { id: 1112, src: "https://freeimage1.jpg" },        
           { id: 1113, src: "https://freeimage2.jpg" },   
         ]
     }),    
  };
</script>
```

**Chrome console shows an error:**
Cannot find module 'https://freeimage1.jpg'

Comment: did you tried `<img :src="prod.src" /> `

Comment: if the images are accessible through web then it's simply what @Ifaruki stated

Comment: @Ifaruki it works! thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You bind it wrong.

Change this line:

```
<img :src="require(`${prod.src}`)" />
```

To this:

```
<img :src="prod.src" />
```